# Bind ItemsControl with WrapPanel wpf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, data-binding

I've searched a lot before posting this question but I didn't find any reasonable solution.

I'm trying to create grid containing the textboxes using ItemsControl.
Here is my xml:

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="grid">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CatalogName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I've assigned the list of catalog to `grid`. Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetCatalog();
        }

        async void GetCatalog()
        {
            using (var client = new ApiClientT1())
            {
                var data = await client.GetCatalogList();
                if (data.Success)
                {
                    grid.DataContext = data.Catalogs;
                }
                //TODO: Handling Errors/Exceptions
            }
        }
    }
```

But it's not showing any data when I run the program.
Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ItemsControl's `ItemsSource` property, instead of its `DataContext`:

```
grid.ItemsSource = data.Catalogs;
```

Or set its `DataContext` and bind the `ItemsSource` in XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

As a note, it's strange to call an ItemsSource "grid".